# Синонимы-опечатки для меток

Tags: обсуждение, метки, синонимы-меток

Я достаточно часто редактирую сообщения и заметил следующую особенность: править текст вопроса необходимо на русскоязычной раскладке, а метки на англоязычной. Сам факт постоянного переключения утомляет. Интересно, что для меток [c](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) и [c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) раскладку переключать не надо, потому что для них есть русскоязычный синоним.

Предлагаю добавить синонимы для англоязычных меток написанных с использованием русскоязычной раскладки.

Поясню, например, для [php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) синонимом будте [зрз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b7), для [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) - [офмф](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d1%84%d0%bc%d1%84).

Comment: и фягку для azure?

Comment: Почему бы и нет. Звучит отлично.

Comment: [tag:пше-ашдеук-икфтср], [tag:фтвкщшв-фсешмшен]. Коллеги, а мы с вами случайно не вызовем Люцифера?

Comment: хорошо, что еще нет кои-8. феуф, реяр и прочее я сбрюфемхел.

Comment: Пожалуйста, помните, что синонимы не будут видны, но когда вы будете набирать не на той раскладке нужную метку, появится правильный вариант.

Answer (score 1):

А как насчет транслитерации меток? 
Кстати, [питон](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bd) уже есть.

- [пхп](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%85%d0%bf)
- [джава](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0)
- [шарпы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%bf%d1%8b)
- [ажур](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%b6%d1%83%d1%80)
- [андроид](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b4)
- [макось](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8c)
- [винда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b0)
- [линукс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%81)
- [убунта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0)

Comment: А "ажур" это что?

Comment: @avp: думаю, [tag:azure] как-то так читается.